# Extend image canvas with GD or Imagick

Tags: php, gd, image-manipulation, imagick

Let's say I have an 200x100 image, and I resize it to 100x50:

```
// imagick
$imagick->resizeImage($width, $height, Imagick::FILTER_UNDEFINED, 1)

// gd
$image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
imagecopyresampled($image, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, imagesx($src), imagesy($src)))
```

But I want the image to be 120x120. How can extend the canvas to that size, but keep that image I just resized in the same dimensions, in the center? Something like Image->Canvas Size in Photoshop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// make the canvas, fill it with $color
$canvas = imagecreatetruecolor(120, 120);
imagefilledrectangle($canvas,0,0,120,120,$color);

// get the image from file...
list($width, $height) = getimagesize('myimage.jpg');
$img = getimagefromjpg('myimage.jpg');

// resample image and place it in center of canvas
$x = intval(($width - 100) / 2);
$y = intval(($height - 50) / 2); 
imagecopyresampled($canvas, $img, $x, $y, 0, 0, 100, 50, $width, $height);

// output etc. ...
```